# How to get user name by array values--wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get username instead of userid

Here is my code

```
$Assignedto = $_POST['ticket_id'];  //displays ticket id

$assignee =$wpdb->get_var("select assigned_to from {$wpdb->prefix}wpsp_ticket where id ='$Assignedto' ");//outputs 183,246,239

$EXP_array =explode(',', $assignee);//converts to array list

var_dump($EXP_array);//output { [0]=> string(3) "183" [1]=> string(3) "246" [2]=> string(3) "239" }
```

my output should be

```
183 = Amar
246 = Akbar
239 = Anthony
```

Expected Result=Amar,Akbar, Anthony

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: And where does these names come from?

Comment: @u_mulder names should come from db ( wp_users)  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

Comment: We have direct function to get data but i am not able to pass all the 3 values at time(array)

Comment: Do you think we can imagine your "direct function"?

Comment: is there any other way to get.thing is if its single value i can get using that  function get_user_data

Comment: Call this function in a loop

Comment: @u_mulder Tried                                                                          foreach( $EXP_array as $user_id) {
  var_dump($user_id);
  $user_object = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $username = $user_info->user_login;
  
 }

Comment: @u_mulder is that a right way

Comment: @JMR Yes. You can go with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code!!

```
$Assignedto = $_POST['ticket_id'];  //displays ticket id

$assignee =$wpdb->get_var("select assigned_to from {$wpdb->prefix}wpsp_ticket where id ='$Assignedto' ");
//outputs 183,246,239

$EXP_array =explode(',', $assignee);//converts to array list
$tmp = array();
foreach( $EXP_array as $user_id) { 
    $user_object = get_userdata( $user_id ); 
    $tmp[] = $user_info->user_login; 
} 
$EXP_array = $tmp;
var_dump($EXP_array);
```

This will give the exact result you needed.